# How to create file on server with special privileges on Asp .net using visual basic?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

One of the client requirements is that the server generate files and store them on a special folder. This files created can not be modified by users or deleted.
So the only way I thought is to generate this files with elevated privileges so a normal user can't delete or modify them.
But the question is how can I generate a file with this privileges that normal users can interact with this files... only download from server.

I use this code to generate  the file... But I don't know how to configure it for elevated privileges.

This is the button which generate the file and allow to download it:

```
Protected Sub ibtGenerar_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    oArchivoTelecredito.NombreArchivo = txtNombreArchivo.Text
    oArchivoTelecredito.SesionDetalleArchivosTelecredito = New List(Of DetalleArchivoTelecreditoBE)
    Dim oArchivoTelecreditoSL As New ArchivoTelecreditoSL
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & oArchivoTelecredito.NombreArchivo & ".txt")
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.BinaryWrite(oArchivoTelecreditoSL.GeneraArchivoTelecredito(oArchivoTelecredito, Server.MapPath(oArchivoTelecredito.NombreArchivo)))
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

This is the function which create the file on server:

```
Public Function GeneraArchivoTelecredito(ByVal telecredito As ArchivoTelecreditoBE, ByVal ruta As String) As Byte()
            Dim lineas As Integer = telecredito.SesionDetalleArchivosTelecredito.Count + 1
            Dim registro(0 To lineas) As String
            registro(0) = Me.ObtenerCabeceraArchivoTelecredito(telecredito)
            Dim archivo = ruta & ".txt"
            Using escritor As New StreamWriter(archivo)
                For index = 0 To lineas
                    escritor.WriteLine(registro(index))
                Next
                escritor.Close()
            End Using
            Dim lector As FileStream
            lector = File.Open(archivo, FileMode.Open)
            Dim bytes(lector.Length) As Byte
            lector.Read(bytes, 0, lector.Length)
            lector.Close()
            Return bytes
        End Function
```

Comment: If you want to set the file to be read-only then you can use File.SetAttributes("PathToFile", FileAttributes.ReadOnly).

Comment: I can be. But if I want to disallow deleting the file. Is it possible?

Comment: See this post - http://serverfault.com/questions/3878/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-file-from-being-deleted - you should probably set the permissions on the directory not the files themselves.

Comment: But it is possible to set this attributtes on the web config?

Comment: Why would you want to set the attributes in the web.config file? Your web application should be running under some account if it is in an application pool. Give this account rights to create files in that directory, and give all regular users read-only rights to the directory.

Comment: Can you put it as an answer to mark it?

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the file to be read-only then you can use

```
File.SetAttributes("PathToFile", FileAttributes.ReadOnly).
```

You could also set the permissions on the directory itself instead of the individual files - see this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/3878/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-a-file-from-being-deleted